# Add an audit to documentation that asks a programming question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-audits, documentation-review

I've seen a lot of questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/106216)) get approved as documentation, and they follow a distinct pattern, so I'm suggesting that there be a type of audit task in documentation that attempts to ask a programming question. My imagined steps for creating these tasks are this:

1. Take a zero-scoring but open question from Q&A (the questions posted in Documentation seem to be very similar to these).
2. Create a new topic with the code blocks from the questions inside examples. The example titles would be the last sentences before the respective code blocks, or "Code" if it's at the beginning.
3. Add the body of the question (without code blocks) in the Remarks section.
4. Use the title of the question as the topic title.

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/106256

Comment: Who would even approve this?

Comment: @JarrodDixon: have you actually implemented the audit I suggested, or did you just implement the "not documentation" reject reason?

Answer (score 30):

**Dev Edit: This suggestion has been implemented**

I agree with this, but I think we need to go further than that.

I think that the following Reject reason (based on "Attempt to Reply" in Suggested Edits, and the "Not an Answer" flag) should be added (title by [J F](/users/5244995)):

> **Not Documentation**
>   This change does not attempt to improve the topic, and only asks about it. It should be an improvement request, or a question posted in Q&A.

Comment: `Not Documentation`?

Comment: Great idea - on our plate to do.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Really sad that we need to, though, [but, alas, you cannot stop the programming questions.](/a/336273)

Comment: This new rejection reason has been pushed out.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, yeah, I noticed your edit.

Comment: DOUBLE NOTIFICATIONS... HAVE ANOTHER! :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon no audits :(

Answer (score 3):

Some examples of this problem (that didn’t make it through, fortunately!):

- [Python coding Ascii art help](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/93169)
- [*Wipes the [tag:ios] NSUserDefaults topic and replaces it with a question*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95547)
- [*Picture-only*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/91709)
- [SQLite.swift Compiler Error](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/90960)
- [*Question as proposed change reason*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/89895)
- [*Added to the Versions section*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/106256) — via [Some Person](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6388243/some-person)
- [Please fix my code](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/110086)

Comment: more worrying is some of those examples had people approve them :(

Comment: Did anyone issued a flag?

Comment: @KevinL  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2952074/bsoulier look on his face tells you everything, lol...

Comment: Idk- I like that picture better than [this one](http://www.logrr.com/img/team/benjaminsoulier.jpg)